# Dynamic search and Linq to return a Comma separated string

Tags: c#, linq, search, dynamic

I used LINQ to concatenate multiple rows into single row. I have problems At dynamic search page usage.

```
User  Hobby
--------------
Bob   Football 
Bob   Golf 
Bob   Basketball
Sue   Sleeping 
Sue   Drinking
```

to

```
User  Hobby
--------------
Bob   Football, Golf, Tennis 
Sue   Sleeping, Drinking
```

with

```
var users = new[]
{
    new { User="Bob", Hobby="Football" },
    new { User="Bob", Hobby="Golf" },
    new { User="Bob", Hobby="Tennis" },
    new { User="Sue", Hobby="Sleeping" },
    new { User="Sue", Hobby="Drinking" },
};

 var userList = users.ToList();

 var result1 = (from user in users
                group user by user.User into groupedUserList
                select new { 
                    user = groupedUserList.Key, 
                    hobby = groupedUserList.Select(x => x.Hobby).Aggregate((a, b) => (a + ", " + b))
                });

 var result2 = (from groupeduser in ug
 select new{ groupeduser.user, hobby =string.Join(",", groupeduser.hobby)});
```

If i add search field with hobby

> with result1= result1.Where(t => t.Hobby.Contains("ball"));

it will throw error ---> Aggregate not supported

> with result2= result2.Where(t => t.Hobby.Contains("ball"));

it will throw System.String Join(System.String, System.String[]) not supported translate to SQL

Comment: in `from groupeduser in ug`, what is `ug`?

Comment: if you want to convert Contains function into linq to sql you can use `users.Where(s => SqlMethods.Like(s.Hobby, "%{0}%"))`

Comment: does `result1.ToList().Where(t => t.Hobby.Contains("ball"));` work?

Comment: yes it will work as well, but the difference is that after `toList` you are getting all data from the database and performing c# function `Contains` for each record, meanwhile using `SqlMethods` creates sql query which contains like statement.

Comment: The main problem is filter the result set after "result1 and result2" with contains method for hobbies. your approach is better for performance way according of use toList. but i take error when i try. for bob example needed result is Bob  - Football, Golf, Tennis  for search page of hobby text is entered ball  @vladimir-gabrielyan

Comment: okay in that case try to use something like this `users.Where(u => users.Where(s => s.Hobby == "Sleeping").Select(s => s.User).Contains(u.User)).Select(s => s);` after that put all your grouping staff. It is kind of scanning one table twice, if your table is not too big you can use that.

Comment: i have 1.000.000 records :( @vladimir-gabrielyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's supported only in `Linq-To-Objects`, so you can use `AsEnumerable` or `ToList`:

```
var userGroups = from user in users
                 group user by user.User into groupedUserList
                 select new { 
                     user = groupedUserList.Key, 
                     userHobbies = groupedUserList.Select(x => x.Hobby)
                };

foreach(var grp in userGroups.AsEnumerable())
    Console.WriteLine("user:{0} hobbies:{1}"
        , grp.user
        , String.Join(",", grp.userHobbies));
```

If you want to filter the result you should do that before you load it into memory(f.e. with `ToList`). So use `Where` first:

```
var usersGroupsWithBallHobbies = userGroups
    .Where(g => g.userHobbies.Any(hobby => hobby.Contains("ball")));
foreach(var grp in usersGroupsWithBallHobbies.AsEnumerable())
    ...
```

This `Any` + `String.Contains` should work also in `Linq-To-Entities` (>= .NET 4)

Comment: After toList  getting all data from the database and The main problem is filter thre result set after result1 and result2 with contains method for hobbies. @tim-schmelter

Comment: @stackCoder: edited my answer to show you how to filter for "ball"-substrings

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from user in users
         group user by user.User into groupedUserList
         select new { User = groupedUserList.Key, 
                      Hobby = string.Join(", ", 
                          groupedUserList.Select(item => item.Hobby).ToList()) };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupedByUser = users.GroupBy(u => u.User)
                         .Select(g => new { User = g.Key, Hobbies = String.Join(", ", g.Select(u => u.Hobby)) })
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your "SQL-supported" request first like fetching your data grouped by hobbies with your `where` clause, like this :

```
var result1 = (from user in users
               where user.Hobby.Contains("Ball")
               group user by user.User);
```

Then you load the data in memory using `ToList()` and perform the concatenation of hobbies, like this :

```
var result2 = result1
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new {
        User = x.Key,
        Hobbies = string.Join(",", x.Select(pair => pair.Hobby))
    });
```

To sum up :

- `result1` contains your **Linq-to-Sql** query.
- `result2` contains your **In-Memory** query, it is your final result.

Comment: I have no problem for take the result set. The main problem is filter thre result set after result1 and result2 with contains method for hobbies @nverinaud

Comment: Why want you to join the hobbies before using contains ? If you have a specific column in your database it is more efficient to do the where on that column then the group by then the join !

Comment: The output will for "ball" Bob => Football only if i do where on that column before join not Football, Golf, Tennis @nverinaud

Answer (score 0):

```
var hobbySearchKey = "ball";

users
    .GroupBy(_ => _.User, _ => _.Hobby) // group users with hobbies
    .Where(_ => _.Any(hobby => hobby.Contains(hobbySearchKey))) // filter only users whose hobbies contain a search key
    .Select(_ => new { User = _.Key, Hobbies = string.Join(",", _)}); // concatenate hobbies
```

MSDN on [Any LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386935(v=vs.100).aspx)

MSDN Blogs on [string.Contains](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/)

Comment: The output will for Bob  =>   Football only  not Football, Golf, Tennis  @andriy-tolstoy

Comment: @stackCoder - my fault. Of cause it needs to be grouped at first. I edited the query accordingly.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I have added some resources with useful explanations.

Comment: But web links are also discouraged. The answers should be complete and self contained to make Stack Overflow a repository of knowledge, not a repository of links. The explanation should be inside the answer, like some of the other answers.